# How do I fix an 'ImportError: No module named imbox' exception

Tags: python, import

```
from imbox import Imbox
```

results in an `ImportError: No module named imbox`.

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: did you search what this error means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you dont have imbox installed. You can do this using pip in your commandline.

Depending on your pip version the command is either:

```
pip install imbox
```

or if your pip version is higher 3

```
pip3 install imbox
```

find out your pip version with

```
pip --version
```

If you dont even have pip installed you can findout how here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: i have imbox installed , but unable to import it

Comment: then what does `pip show imbox` return for you? And maybe check if you are able to install and import other modules

Answer (score 0):

This means that package `imbox` is not installed.

You can install it, using this command:

```
pip install imbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think imbox is an automatically installed package.
Try installing imbox first by typing

> pip install imbox

in your command prompt

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems weird ,but what caused the issue was i created just a file.py and started coding in that,
creating a new project and then the file resolved the issue.

Comment: After you created the project, your IDE probably installed the `imbox` package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).